# Request.QueryString returns inconsistent values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, query-string

I am using encoded query strings, but experiencing a problem.

**URL:** `default.aspx?qX81JvYf9eQ%3d-dmVoaWNsZUlkPTE0MTM%3d`

On the `Page_Load` I retrieve the query string using `Request.QueryString`, but it returns different results on IIS Express and my local IIS 8 server:

**IIS Express:**
`qX81JvYf9eQ%3d-dmVoaWNsZUlkPTE0MTM%3d` (correct)

**IIS 8:**
`qX81JvYf9eQ%3d-dmVoaWNsZUlkPTE0MTM%3d%3f`

IIS 8 has an additional '%3f'.

Why is this happening?  I'm assuming it must be due to some IIS setting somewhere.

Comment: %3f is an encoded question mark.

Comment: Yep, I know, but where does it come from?

Comment: Shouldn't you also give the QS parameter a name? Like `default.aspx?foo=qX81JvYf9eQ%3d-dmVoaWNsZUlkPTE0MTM%3d` (note the *foo=*)...

Comment: It  decodes down to that.  My problem is why Request.QueryString returns different results on IIS Express and IIS 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to a malfunctioning [URL Rewriter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine).  Very painful and a lot of time wasted.